# window.location fails to work in IE (IE9)

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.location

**What Am I trying to do:** redirection to home page and to previous page with id.

**Whats going wrong:** fails to work in IE (9) works on Firefox.

**What I have tried:**

On click events:

```
<input type="hidden" id="product_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['product_id']; ?>" />
        <td><input type="submit" value="Update" onClick="update(); return false;" /></td>     
        <td><input type="submit" value="Go Back" onClick="redirect('go back'); return false;" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Done" onClick="redirect('home'); return false;" /></td>
```

redirect function:

```
function redirect(redirect){


    var id = $('#product_id').val();    

    if (redirect == "go back"){
        window.location.href = 'displayProduct.php?product_id='+id;
    }
    else if (redirect == "home"){
        window.location.href = 'index.php';
    }

}
```

I also tried adding a `alert('1');` inside the redirect function which doesn't appear to be firing in IE.

Am I missing something..?

Comment: have you tried `location.pathname`? `window.location.pathname = '/displayProduct.php?product_id='+id;` and `window.location.pathname = '/index.php';`.  Otherwise, I would try building the full url including the hostname and such and trying that with `location.href`.

Comment: That is navigation; it shouldn't use `<input>` elements. You should use anchor tags, `<a>`, with `href` attributes like any other link. If you want them to look like a button you can do so with a style. Tying navigation to JavaScript is brittle and not needed here.

Comment: Why don't you set `window.location=<path>`?

Comment: Do not name the argument variable the same thing as the function name!

Comment: @ArunPJohny, that makes no difference

Comment: @ssorallen: I see what you mean but it wouldn't even fire my `alert` which has got me puzzled.

Comment: Have you tried making the attribute all lowercase, `onclick` instead of `onClick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible IE is throwing an error on this line:

```
var id = $('#product_id').val();
```

Which could be preventing further execution. If you don't already, make sure script debugging is not disabled in IE as well as show errors is turned on:

[image: screenshot]